# Unable to pass stringstream to constructor

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, stringstream

I am using [SimpleINI](http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini/) to get values into `std::stringstream my_string;` -

```
CSimpleIniCaseA::TNamesDepend::const_iterator i;
for (i = values.begin(); i != values.end(); ++i)
my_string << i->pItem <<"\n";
cout<<my_string.str()<<endl;
```

cout is working fine. I am able to print values on console.

But when I pass this string steam to BOOST ASIO Server constructor like this-

```
server tcp(tcp_service,my_string.str());
```

I get below compiler error-

```
‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
```

I am able to pass other data types like `char *`, but not string steam. What is wrong?

Comment: Could you post a small example that reproduces this? The error indicates that private assignment operator is being invoked somewhere but it is not possible to tell where from the posted code.

Comment: `my_string.str()` is a string, not a stream.

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes -thanks! I changed the constructor and now its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you did something like

```
server tcp(tcp_service,my_string.str());
```

But there you pass a string to the constructor, not a stringstream.
Either change your constructor, or remove the `.str()` from `my_string.str()`